# DrupalChat module polling method

Tags: 7, performance

I am using [drupalchat](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupalchat) module for my website. And I wanted to check which polling method is best - "Normal AJAX" or "Long Polling". Actually We are facing performance issue. Currently we are using "Normal AJAX" as polling method. 
Can somebody suggest which polling method we should use and why?

Answer (score 0):

I had a experience about that, when using Ajax each short time each user and all of open each pages has requested to server ( if you look at firebug console you see what I mean ), another method is Long Polling method that also it is not the best way ( although it is better than Ajax method if very quick response time is not important for you), **In Both cause heavy load on server (especially memory exhausted)**.ajax and polling is old method to interactive real time applications like chat
**I strongly recommend you using Nodejs method, Nodejs is very good for realtime chat system**

So use  **Drupalchat nodejs** integration solution

> f you use node.js as backend in this module, then it will be highly
>   scalable. There are two ways to use this backend:
>
> ```
>  First way is to setup your own node.js server and install Nodejs Integration module. This is currently under development.
> If you don't want to or can't setup your own node.js server, then you can checkout our ready to use node.js server. If you opt for this
> ```
>
> method, then there is no need to install any additional
>   software/package on your web server. To do so, please visit us at
>   https://iflychat.com.

another solution is using [nodejs_chat drupal module](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodejs_chat) ( in both solution you require nodejs on yourserver).